# Colocar un objeto en una lista de C++

Tags: c++, poo, punteros, objeto

Tengo el siguiente struct que es una lista de puertos. Tiene un puntero al siguiente y un objeto de tipo "puerto":

```
struct colp {
    puerto p;
    colp *sig;
}; typedef struct colp *colpuertos;
```

La clase puerto es la siguiente:

```
class puerto{
private:
    string id;
    string nombre;

public:
    //getters
    string getterid();
    string getternombre();

    //setters
    void setterid(string id2);
    void setternombre(string nom);

    //constructor parametrizado
    puerto(string id, string nom){
        this->setterid(id);
        this->setternombre(nom);
    }
};

//getters
string puerto::getterid(){
    return id;
}

string puerto::getternombre(){
    return nombre;
}

//setters
void puerto::setterid(string id2){
    id=id2;
}

void puerto::setternombre(string nom){
    nombre=nom;
}
```

En el main puedo crear puertos y colecciones, pero en el momento que intento conectar uno de los puertos a la colección da un "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Intente creando el puerto y luego asignándolo a la colección pero no fue posible.

Mi main:

```
int main(){
puerto prueba1("20", "Geremias");
colpuertos coleccion;
coleccion = creoVacio();
coleccion->p = prueba1;
return 0;
}
```

En cuanto a la función creoVacio tan solo es un retorno a null:

```
colpuertos creoVacio(){
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Trauma eliminé las cosas innecesarias y agregué solo el código necesario para resolver el problema

Comment: **No puedes** devolver `NULL` e intentar usar ese valor devuelto ... Creo que deberías revisar algunos conceptos sobre memoria y memoria dinámica.

Comment: Si quito el NULL no estaría inicializado, lo que devolvería un "invalid pointer".

Comment: ¿ Y un `NULL` es un *valid pointer* ? Igual el nombre, *nulo*, lo escogieron por algo. Arreglar tu código es trivial; pero explicártelo es hacer un tutorial sobre el manejo de memoria. Y ya hay muchísimos disponibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu programa declaras un tipo *colpuertos* como un  puntero hacia un area de la memoria que tiene una estructura *colp*. La función  *crearVacio* supuestamente debería crear la estructura *colp* y devolver el puntero hacia esa estructura. Sin embargo, lo que devuelve es *NULL* o un puntero hacia la memoria 0, que tambien es un puntero invalido.

Si quieres inicializar a *NULL* tu variable *coleccion* hazlo en la misma declaración:

```
 colpuertos coleccion=NULL;
```

Para que la función *crearVacio* realmente te devuelva un puntero hacia una estructura *colp* inicializada debería ser asi:

```
colpuertos creoVacio(){
    colpuertos  cp = new struct colp;
    cp->sig=NULL;
    return cp;
}
```

Con ello creas la estructura colp e inicializas el puntero *sig* a NULL.